# How do I rewrite an Nginx request to a specific local file with a specific pattern

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble getting my head around the use of regexp and extracting variables in Nginx.

I would like to write all requests for files that contain the word `/development/` in the path to a specific directory.

`/development/1.1000038/assets/css/something.css`

Should return the file:

`/usr/share/nginx/html/public_html/assets/css/something.css`

And:

`/development/1.1000038/assets/js/something.js`

Should return the file:

`/usr/share/nginx/html/public_html/assets/js/something.js`

Etc...

The URL structure of the incoming requests will always be the same as long as `/development/` is present.  i.e. `/development/` then `/(version_number)/` then finally the actual part of the URL I wish to use.

I seem to be able to match and intercept any incoming requests with the word `/development/` in them but am having trouble extracting and using the remaining part of the URL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

This is what I have tried:

```
location ~ /development/(.*?)/(.*) {
   try_files /usr/share/nginx/html/public_html/$2 /dev/null;
}
```

My thinking was that I should be matching the `/development/` section.  The version number with `(.*?)` then the rest of the URL with the final `(.*)`

Then I assumed I could just take that `$2` variable and use it in my `try_files` directive.  Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work.

I have also tried just matching and using the part I actually need:

```
location ~ /development/[A-Za-z0-9\.]+/(.*) {
        try_files /usr/share/nginx/html/public_html/$1 /dev/null;
}
```

I'm not great with regular expressions at all, but in the online tester I am using they appear to match the correct parts of the URL.

Comment: Do you have a problem with matching the whole URL or just with replacing? If it's the second thing, you should edit your question and post your attempts at doing it.

Comment: Edit as requested...

Answer (score 3):

Through sheer trial and error I eventually realised what I was doing wrong.

It turns out that `try_files` uses the `root` param as a prefix to any file you try to request.

Therefore I was effectively applying the root path twice.  By removing the root path either of my above examples works fine.

```
location ~ /development/[A-Za-z0-9\.]+/(.*) {
        try_files /$1 /dev/null;
}
```